# How to show a popupMenu on top of a view, Lollipops style?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, popupmenu

On Lollipop, the guidelines are to show popupMenus on top of views, and not below/above them (taken from [**here**](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-simple-menus)):

[image]

Thing is, according to what I've noticed, they have an anchor, which puts their location near the selected view, but not on top of it.

Even using "MenuPopupHelper" of the support libary (which is an internal class) has failed for me.

How do I achieve the material-design behavior, even on pre-Lollipop versions of Android?

Comment: [DropDownPreference](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/android-m-preview/src/com/android/settings/notification/DropDownPreference.java)

Comment: @adneal I meant about any kind of view. this includes Spinner, for example.